# how can I do a point process model in spatstat on 1 km resolution

Tags: spatstat

I would like to do a point process analysis to model point patterns on 1 km square resolution. I have three layers of covariates as pixel images named; rd, pd and ras. The PPP object is on a polygonal boundary enclosing [-3.1523926, -2.5752286] x [53.31128, 53.70412] units

I have tried the quadscheme function `Q <- quadscheme(data, method="grid", eps=1)` passed the quad class Q into the ppm formula, `model1 <- ppm(Q~ras/rd+pd)`

It cants return any results. any help is highly appreciated

Comment: We need access to data and more details to be able to help you. Did you read the documentation for `ppm()` and the corresponding examples? Your window of observation is enclosed in a rectangle of size approximately 0.6 x 0.4 units, which seems to fit poorly with your desire to do analysis on a 1x1 resolution. If you are new to the subject I can (admittedly biased) recommend our `spatstat` book: http://book.spatstat.org/

Answer (score 0):

You say the `ppm` command didn't return any results. But you used an assignment, `model1 <- ppm(...)`. This would not produce any printed output. You could print the result: try typing `model1` or `print(model1)` or `coef(model1)`.

You say you want to "model point patterns on 1 km square resolution". Does this mean that the point pattern data are (a) coordinates rounded to the nearest 1km, (b) indicators of the presence/absence of points within each 1km pixel in a pixel grid, (c) spatial coordinates recorded with reasonable accuracy but which you want to analyse by discretising to 1km pixels?

If (c) is correct, then you could use the `spatstat` function `slrm` instead of `ppm`. Just `slrm(data ~ ras + pd + rd)` should work.

The command `quadscheme(data, method="grid", eps=1)` does not discretise the spatial coordinates and does not help you with objective (c). It's complicated; I recommend you don't use `quadscheme` at all, as this is a rather advanced feature. Instead, if `data` is already a point pattern of class `"ppp"`, you could use `data` instead of `Q` in your call to the model-fitting function `ppm`.

Example data would help.

Comment: Thank you, Mr @Adrian Baddeley, This clarification is very good but I have only presence-only data which I want to use to predict how various habitats were represented by the surveys by using the point process model and later use cdf.test goodness of fit to see how each variable fit into the model.

Comment: Let us illustrate it using Murchison data